# How to remove an element in a nested map (Flutter Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a nested map as follows:

```
Map x = {
  'A' : {
    'name' : 'Will',
    'age' : 60
  },
  'B' : {
    'name' : 'Smith',
    'age' : 57
  }
};
```

So I just want to remove the `age` at `B` only and it will be like this:

```
{A: {name: Will, age: 60}, B: {name: Smith}}
```

I'm not sure how to use `.removeWhere` for nested maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most obvious solution is this:

```
x['B'].remove('age');
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to use `.remove` function of list

`list['B'].remove('age');`

output

[output log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2okYU.png)